# Should I do a donation mission?

Tags: elite-dangerous

In Elite: Dangerous, some factions are offering donation missions, that offer a reputation increase. Should I take these missions and donate the money, or are they worthless?

Answer (score 1):

Donation missions, as you may have noticed, vary from value, anywhere from 25,000 credits all the way up to 300,000 credits or more. In general, try to avoid the high-cost donation missions, and definitely take the 25,000 credit donation missions when they're available.

Keep in mind that the donation only increases your reputation with the faction and/or superpower that the mission is associated with. If you don't need to raise your reputation with a faction, then don't waste your money. However, if you're purposely trying to increase your reputation with a faction, then the donation missions provide an easy mechanism for you to do so, without having to perform complex mission tasks.

Comment: They're also useful if you're specifically looking for good missions from that faction. You can go from Neutral to Cordial easily with a few donations and then get some better paying missions from them.

Comment: @CmdrFreiheit Agreed! That's kinda what I was shooting for with the last sentence. :) Cheers mate!